# dependency problems, including gcc-5-base and other packages

Tags: package-management, dependencies

can someone help me:

```
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libatk1.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.31.2) but it is not installed
libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.21-7 is installed
libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is installed
libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.21) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is installed
libcairo2-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not installed
libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
libhighgui-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev but it is not installed
libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
libopencv-contrib-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not installed
libopencv-legacy-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not installed
libopencv-objdetect-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not installed
libopencv-ocl-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not installed
libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
libubsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
```

I can't install any software any more because of this dependencies problem.

I have already tried all of the `apt-get` commands (`clean`, `update`, `upgrade`, `install -f`, `autoremove`). Nothing happens, the problem persists. I even re-edited my source list :/

---

Requested command outputs:

```
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-updates multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-proposed multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-backports multiverse main universe restricted
```

new results :

```
root@anonymoon-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~# apt-cache policy gcc-5-base libc6 locales
gcc-5-base:
  Installed: 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:
  Installed: 2.21-7
  Candidate: 2.21-7
  Version table:
 *** 2.21-7 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.7 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-12.1
  Candidate: 2.13+git20120306-12.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.13+git20120306-12.1 0
        500 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.13+git20120306-12 0
        500 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

while trying to install :

```
root@anonymoon-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~# sudo apt-get clean
root@anonymoon-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~# sudo apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatk1.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.31.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.21) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.7 is to be installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.7 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.21-7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.7 is to be installed
 libcairo2-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libhighgui-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libopencv-contrib-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-legacy-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-objdetect-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-ocl-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libubsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-7) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please copy and run this command and [edit] your question to add the output: `grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/ | sed -re 's/^\/etc\/apt\/sources\.list((\.d\/)?|(:)?)//' -e 's/(.*\.list):/\[\1\] /' -e 's/deb http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\/(.*?)\/ubuntu .*/ppa:\1/'` It will list all your enabled PPAs and repositories. Also add the output of `apt-cache policy gcc-5-base libc6 locales` please. Then notify me with a comment when you're done. Thank you!

Comment: I'm new in this forum @ByteCommander

Comment: I need 10 réputations to add two source code in one comment can I send you by mail my results?

Comment: I'm a new user...

Comment: thank you @ByteCommander , I édited my post thank you again

Comment: Please run the following command and also add their output to your question: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists ; sudo apt-get update` This will delete and completely re-download your package index files. Then run `apt-cache policy gcc-5-base libc6 locales` again and update the old output you already included to your question with the new one. Leave me a comment when you're done.

Comment: I'm done updating the results @ByteCommander

Comment: The output of `sudo apt-get update` as well, please. It seems like there's an error and you can't successfully get all lists. Because `gcc-5-base` must have an installation candidate in the main repository, but yours only has one in the local cache.

Comment: ok sir her's the update results i've got after the remove list

Comment: Ah, no. My mistake. `gcc-5-base` is not available for 14.04 but only since 15.04. So you received those other packages from an unsupported PPA as well. What PPAs or other foreign repositories did you recently install and remove?

Comment: I did install a lot of stuff while trying to resolve the problem I don't really remember

Comment: Okay. Start with `sudo apt-get clean` and then run `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.7`. I almost expect the second command to result in more errors, but it's worth a try. We need to identify all packages that don't have an installation candidate in the official installed repositories and remove or downgrade them. I'll try to think of a way how to do this...

Comment: so how can I remove those unsopported ppa

Comment: The PPAs are removed, but not the packages you installed from them. Maybe this command can find out which packages we need to process, but it requires `aptitude` to be installed: `aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, !?version(CANDIDATE))'`

Comment: The program 'aptitude' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install aptitude

Comment: You can probably install `aptitude` despite the dependency issues using `apt-get download aptitude && sudo dpkg --force-all -i aptitude*.deb`. Then run the command from my last comment again and add the output.

Comment: aptitude: error while loading shared libraries: libcwidget.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Ouch. That makes me think you severely broke something. Probably having installed/upgraded to a foreign `libc6` version has broken more things than I expected on the first sight... Probably backing up your data and doing a reinstall might be faster and easier than trying to fix this. :/ Can you do that or do we have to take the effort?

Comment: no problem I will reinstall ubuntu from the start :) thank you a lot for your efforts, I'll take your answers as a solution to my question because I know i broke something in the kernel x) thank you again for your efforts :) (y)

Comment: No, it's not in the kernel but your current version of `libc` (shared libraries for all programs written in C which is quite a lot) is incompatible with most other installed packages. Next time, be careful with PPAs and only add those you need. Good luck with your fresh installation and sorry that I could not really help you.

Comment: no thank you a lot you did help me , now I will be more careful :) how can I vote for you or there is something I can do to recommand you ?

Comment: As I was not able to write an answer that solves your problem, there's nothing you can do for me. But that doesn't matter, really.